# Can't read JSON file from internet with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

For my project I ned to be able to get a users Facebook id. I have done quite a bit of searching but cannot find what works for me. Here is what I have right now, it looks to me like it should work but I get a white screen that says the document cannot be found on the server. Any help would be great! And before you ask, yes I am new to javascript, I have done a little reading on it and now am jumping into it.

```
<script>
var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var script = $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/' + user", function(data) {
    var id = data.id[i];
    document.getElementById("usernameid").value=id;
});
</script>

<form action="script" id="Form1">
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit form" /></form>
<input id="usernameid" name="usernameid" type="text" />
```

Comment: And you did add jQuery and place the script after the elements in the DOM

Comment: what do you see in the console? any errors?

Comment: `"http://graph.facebook.com/' + user"` should be changed to `"http://graph.facebook.com/" + user`

Comment: Use you browser's developer tools. Look in the Console. Are there any errors? Look in the Net tab. Is the request being made? Is it going to the URL you expect? Does it get the response you expect?

Comment: I can see at least 5 different things that would break this, and error messages in the console would point you at most of them.

Comment: I am using a Mac and when I bring up the console, nothing is there.

Comment: @Cody_T — Are you sure you are bringing up your browser's developer tool's console and not the OS X console?

Comment: http://note.io/1Egbeqy